# Issue running Python script via cron inside Docker

Tags: ubuntu, cron, docker

I have an official Ubuntu 14.04.1 container running via Docker.

cron is working fine, I added `* * * * * /bin/echo "working" >> /test` to my crontab using `crontab -e` and then I started cron with `start cron` and it worked as expected.

My script is running fine, I already did `chmod +x main.py` and I can execute it via `./main.py`, my 'services.log' gets all the outputs normally, no crashes.

But when I add it to the crontab, `10 * * * * /root/bumpr/main.py` and do a `start cron` nothing happens and nothing is printed on my 'services.log'.

What's the problem here?

Comment: It is possible python is crashing. Do you have the right shebang? Can you post the `main.py`.

Comment: Why do you test `./main.py` from the commandline and do a `/root/bumpr/main.py` in the crontab. Are you 100% sure that is the right path? Test on the commandline with the path you cut and paste into the crontab.

Comment: The shebang is on line 1, `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. Running via terminal, `cd /root/bumpr` and `./main.py` works. The path is indeed `/root/bumpr/main.py`, checked already.

Comment: Just to be pendantic, as @Anthon mentioned, you didn't run it the same way.  At the command line, type: `/root/bumpr/main.py` (don't `cd` to the directory first!).

Comment: OK, terminal: `/root/bumpr/main.py` works fine, the script does what it needs to and I get the outputs on my 'services.log' as expected.

Comment: @Juan Where is `python3` installed, and is that PATH specified in the crontab? `/usr/bin/env` only searches through `PATH`.

Comment: It seems you deleted your answer, my reply was: `type python3` >> `python3 is /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @Juan I had seen that and invalidated my answer. I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem here.

**SOLUTION**: All you need is:

```
env > /django_app/.env
```

**REASON**: Apparently crontab session execution has no env vars set. This might be some different way of dealing with env vars controlled by docker which makes the command runs on the bash but not through crontab.

**OTHERWISE**: In case none of it is related to your problem. Try it on your crontab config and check out the log:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /django_app/manage.py <your_command_here> 2>/django_app/crontab_error.log
```

Alther - para.alves@gmail.com